# how I can add the `Certificates` folder in local docker environment?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-3.1

My docker containers works fine on Virtual Machine where I have related pfx certificate and configuration files reside in home folder `/home/myVM/Certificates`. In this folder I have pfx certificate file along with one JSON configuration.

My docker compose defines volumes like below,

```
 volumes:
    # Certificates folder should be present in the host VM with all certificates along with CertificateConfigurations.json
  - "./Certificates:/app/certs:ro"
```

Now when I am running docker container in local environment (my laptop) where I don't have `Certificates` folders like VM, it is searching for it.

Question, how I can add the `Certificates` folder in local docker environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create the `Certificates` folder in your Dockerfile. If you're using a third party image you can just build on top of it e.g.

```
FROM xyz:123
RUN mkdir /path-to-certs/Certificates
COPY ./certs/cert.pfx /path-to-certs/Certificates
```

and then in you're docker compose file:

```
services:

   xyz:
      build:
         context: /relative-path-to-dockerfile
      ...
```

and run `docker compose up --build`

Alternatively you could exec into the container to add the `Certificates` folder, but you'd need to do this each time you run a new container instance...

Comment: Thanks, but could you please let me know how to add files to the folder `Certificates`?

Comment: Edited response - you can copy files using the `COPY` command in the dockerfile, you could also use a bind mount to dir on host machine, volume, etc...

Comment: I am using `RUN mkdir /home/Certificates` , but don't see any folder. Any reason you can suggest?

Comment: Did u miss the `--build` when u ran docker compose? Perhaps try getting it working with just docker before using docker compose i.e. `docker build ...` then `docker run ...`